# Usage of Fermat primes in RSA

Tags: rsa

Why are Fermat primes ($2^{2^n}+1$) useful as $e$ (the public key) in RSA encryption?

I understand why $2^n+1$ primes are useful, because they would simply be `100...001` in binary, which for computers is faster in calculations. But why is it important that the exponent is also a power of 2?

Comment: Hint: what is a necessary condition for $2^n+1$ to be prime?

Comment: One part of the question is not addressed yet: why would one want $e$ prime in RSA? Hint: consider how hard it is to meet the requirement $\gcd(e,p-1)=1$ for $e=2^4+1$ and $e=2^5+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All primes of the form $2^n+1$ have the form $2^{2^n}+1$.

As [the wikipedia article on Fermat numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) says:

> If $2^n + 1$ is prime, and $n > 0$, it can be shown that $n$ must be a power of two. (If n = ab where $1 ≤ a$, $b ≤ n$ and $b$ is odd, then $2^n + 1 = (2^a)^b + 1 ≡ (−1)^b + 1 = 0 \pmod{2^a + 1}$. See [Sec. 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers) for complete proof.) In other words, every prime of the form $2^n + 1$ is a Fermat number, and such primes are called Fermat primes.

The only known numbers with this format are 3, 5, 17, 257 and 65537.

Comment: Addition: [Pierre de Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_de_Fermat) wrongly believed/conjectured that $\forall n\in\mathbb N,2^{2^n}+1$ is prime; when he could have disproved that reasonably easily for $n=5$ using [his own little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), and the modern belief is that it is unlikely to hold for any $n>4$.

Comment: I'm not sure they are these are the only Fermat numbers. According to Wikipedia [there are others](https://oeis.org/A000215). Are the ones you mentioned the ones commonly used with RSA?

Comment: @rath We're talking about *primes* with this format. There are infinitely many Fermat numbers, but only these few are prime

Comment: Okay, now I feel stupid. I thought Fermat numbers were of the above format *and* prime.